# Numpy array error from training in keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I've got some pre-saved data from `openai-gym` game `cartpole-v0` and that's what I intend to use to train a model. Same data on [github](https://github.com/Six-wars/data-science/blob/master/openai%20gym/data/saved.npy)

Creating the initial data

```
import gym
from gym import wrappers
import random
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from statistics import median, mean
from collections import Counter
from tqdm import tqdm
from file_creator import new_filename

def initial_population():
    # [OBS, MOVES]
    training_data = []
    # all scores:
    scores = []
    # just the scores that met our threshold:
    accepted_scores = []
    # iterate through however many games we want:
    for _ in tqdm(range(initial_games)):
        score = 0
        # moves specifically from this environment:
        game_memory = []
        # previous observation that we saw
        prev_observation = []
        # for each frame in 200
        for _ in tqdm(range(goal_steps)):
            # choose random action (0 or 1)
            action = random.randrange(0,2)
            # do it!
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

            # notice that the observation is returned FROM the action
            # so we'll store the previous observation here, pairing
            # the prev observation to the action we'll take.
            if len(prev_observation) > 0 :
                game_memory.append([prev_observation, action])
            prev_observation = observation
            score+=reward
            if done: break

        # IF our score is higher than our threshold, we'd like to save
        # every move we made
        # NOTE the reinforcement methodology here. 
        # all we're doing is reinforcing the score, we're not trying 
        # to influence the machine in any way as to HOW that score is 
        # reached.
        if score >= score_requirement:
            accepted_scores.append(score)
            for data in tqdm(game_memory):
                # convert to one-hot (this is the output layer for our neural network)
                if data[1] == 1:
                    output = [0,1]
                elif data[1] == 0:
                    output = [1,0]

                # saving our training data
                training_data.append([data[0], output])

        # reset env to play again
        env.reset()
        # save overall scores
        scores.append(score)

    # just in case you wanted to reference later
    training_data_save = np.array(training_data)
    filename = new_filename('data/saved.npy')
    np.save(filename, training_data_save)

    # some stats here, to further illustrate the neural network magic!
    print('Average accepted score:',mean(accepted_scores))
    print('Median score for accepted scores:',median(accepted_scores))
    print(Counter(accepted_scores))

    return training_data


initial_population()

import numpy as np
training_data = np.load('data/saved.npy')

def x_y(training_data):
    X = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data])
    y = np.array([i[1] for i in training_data])

    return X, y

x, y = x_y(training_data)

y.shape
>>> (270057, 2)

x.shape
>>> (270057, 4)

x[1]
>>> array([-1.98146801e-02,  4.37329833e-01,  2.21470899e-04, -5.45477988e-01])

y[1]
>>> array([0, 1])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
x, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)
```

This is the code for the model

```
    from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

def keras_model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dense(10,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="best_weights.hdf5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True) # save best model

    model.fit(x_train ,y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),callbacks=[monitor,checkpointer], verbose=2,epochs=1000)
    model.load_weights('best_weights.hdf5') # load weights from best model

    return model

model = keras_model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
```

I execute the code and in between it throws an error that the input has a wrong shape

```
muiruri_samuel@vuejs:~/data-science/openai gym$ python3 cartpole2.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARN: gym.spaces.Box autodetected dtype as <class 'numpy.float32'>. Please provide explicit dtype.
Train on 216045 samples, validate on 54012 samples
Epoch 1/1000
2018-08-17 11:40:33.501571: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
 - 66s - loss: 0.6502 - val_loss: 0.6459
Epoch 2/1000
 - 69s - loss: 0.6456 - val_loss: 0.6469
Epoch 3/1000
 - 69s - loss: 0.6450 - val_loss: 0.6457
Epoch 4/1000
 - 67s - loss: 0.6445 - val_loss: 0.6439
Epoch 5/1000
 - 62s - loss: 0.6444 - val_loss: 0.6439
Epoch 6/1000
 - 63s - loss: 0.6440 - val_loss: 0.6442
Epoch 7/1000
 - 63s - loss: 0.6438 - val_loss: 0.6451
Epoch 8/1000
 - 69s - loss: 0.6435 - val_loss: 0.6430
Epoch 9/1000
 - 68s - loss: 0.6435 - val_loss: 0.6436
Epoch 00009: early stopping
  0%|                                                                                   | 0/500 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cartpole2.py", line 196, in <module>
    action = np.argmax(model.predict(prev_obs.reshape(-1,len(prev_obs),1))[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1147, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 749, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 127, in standardize_input_d
ata
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1,
 4, 1)
```

This last line

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1,
 4, 1)
```

Suggest that likely in between the X there's one that instead of being a one row dimension has three dimension. 
Believe the solution then would be to reshape `X` and likely then fix this bug.

**EDIT**

Based on the current suggested proving this bug

```
muiruri_samuel@vuejs:~/data-science/openai gym$ python3 cartpole2.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARN: gym.spaces.Box autodetected dtype as <class 'numpy.float32'>. Please provide explicit dtype.
Train on 216045 samples, validate on 54012 samples
Epoch 1/1000
2018-08-17 15:40:15.992262: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
 - 62s - loss: 0.6510 - val_loss: 0.6455
Epoch 2/1000
 - 62s - loss: 0.6458 - val_loss: 0.6449
Epoch 3/1000
 - 62s - loss: 0.6451 - val_loss: 0.6445
Epoch 4/1000
 - 62s - loss: 0.6445 - val_loss: 0.6477
Epoch 5/1000
 - 56s - loss: 0.6442 - val_loss: 0.6451
Epoch 6/1000
 - 57s - loss: 0.6440 - val_loss: 0.6432
Epoch 7/1000
 - 56s - loss: 0.6439 - val_loss: 0.6436
 - 56s - loss: 0.6442 - val_loss: 0.6451
Epoch 8/1000
 - 56s - loss: 0.6435 - val_loss: 0.6449
Epoch 9/1000
 - 61s - loss: 0.6434 - val_loss: 0.6435
Epoch 10/1000
 - 61s - loss: 0.6434 - val_loss: 0.6432
Epoch 11/1000
 - 64s - loss: 0.6434 - val_loss: 0.6432
Epoch 00011: early stopping
  0%|                                                                                   | 0/500 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cartpole2.py", line 201, in <module>
    action = np.argmax(model.predict(prev_obs.reshape(-1,len(prev_obs),1))[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1147, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 749, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 127, in standardize_input_d
ata
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1,
 4, 1)
```

which forms later on than the prior one.

Checked for outliers and got none

```
counter = 0
for i in x:
    if i.shape != (4,):
        print(counter)
    counter += 1

#no output

counter = 0
for i in y:
    if i.shape != (2,):
        print(counter)
    counter += 1

#no output
```